# Chrome DevTools Network Waterfall - gaps between requests?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I've been doing some refactoring on a slow running web application, and managed to reduce the number of requests and the size of the downloads to help improve the situation. Now the loading time is consistently shorter. However, consistently before there was hardly any time elapsed before the last 2 requests. Now consistently there is a gap.

[image]

**Q1: What do these 'gaps' indicate in Chrome Network view?**

**Q2: Looking at the screenshots, the DOMContentLoaded time vs. the overall Finish time, are there any conclusions I can draw that could help me optimise further?**

Comment: 1. Time spent on stuff that's not a network request. 2.  No.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Record the page load in the Performance panel. See [Get Started With Analyzing Runtime Performance](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/) to get the gist of how to use the panel. [Understanding the network bottleneck](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xpsrtYcBy10) can also help get you oriented.

However, you'll want to press the **Reload page** button (like Sam does in the "understanding the network bottleneck" video) instead of the **Record** button to record the page load performance, as the "get started with analyzing runtime performance" instructs you to do.

Once you've got a recording, the **Main** section shows you all of the main thread activity that occurs while the page is loading. The **Network** section shows you all of the Network requests. You'll probably be able to visually verify that there's a bunch of JavaScript work going on during the gap that you're seeing in your screenshots.

If it's still not clear to you, post a screenshot of your Performance panel recording and I'll help you decode the results.