# How to recreate Chrome Waterfall column (Network tab) that documents time required for different stages of network request for jQuery AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918544/chrome-devtools-network-waterfall-gaps-between-requests) is similar but not helpful.

To provide more feedback to users, we want to mimic the Waterfall column in the Network tab of Chrome, which deconstructs network requests into different stages and times them.

An example is included below.

In the particular, we want to indicate three stages:

- Time uploading a file
- Time processing a file on the server
- Time download results

From the [jQuery AJAX docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), it seems like `beforeSend` could be used to time file uploads. How about download time and time on server (TTFB in screenshot)?

Here's how we implement AJAX calls:

```
async function doRequest() {
    // Set server URL.
    let serverUrl = 'https://test.com/test';

    // Set form data
    let imageFile = imageFile

    // Create request form.
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('imageFile', imageFile);

    // Set request settings.
    let settings = {
        url: serverUrl,
        method: 'POST',
        timeout: 0,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        xhr: function() {
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
               if (xhr.readyState == 2) {
                    if (xhr.status == 200) {
                      xhr.responseType = 'blob';
                    } else {
                      xhr.responseType = 'text';
                    }
               }
            };
            return xhr;
        },
    };

    // Make request.
    try {
        let result = await $.ajax(settings);
        // Handle success
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle failure
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: There is no jQuery code here. Do you want a solution in jQuery only? You can achieve the same thing with the XHR readyState.

Comment: @RandyCasburn the jQuery code is here `let result = await $.ajax(settings);` jQuery is preferred, but anything is helpful, too. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh wow - I saw the raw XMLHttpRequest and didn't scroll down.

Comment: I was going to suggest the [Resource Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resource_Timing_API/Using_the_Resource_Timing_API) but if you want to use jQuery I suppose not. Good Luck.

Comment: Hi @RandyCasburn how can you achieve the same thing with XHR readyState? Do you mind sharing? Thanks!

Comment: There are 5 ready states you can use, 0 - ~ Queuing, 1 - Request Sent, 3 - Headers Received 4. Working 5. Complete. The time between 3 & 4, along with any idle time while Working (4. happens repeatedly) would be ~Waiting. Details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) ::: **BUT**, based up your stated requirements, I must strongly suggest you consider the [Resource Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resource_Timing_API/Using_the_Resource_Timing_API) as the better solution.

Comment: @RandyCasburn With the Resource Timing API, how can you get an event to know when files are done uploading or the response body downloading has started? Could you post as an answer so you can get awarded the points?

Comment: There you go! Some great source code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Resource Loading and Timing

As usual, someone had the same idea and has provided a pre-coded solution.  I discovered these resources in an attempt to help you with this very complicated task. You can use the code as written or place it into a bookmarklet.

I found a detailed article that describes how to use both the [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API) & the [Resource Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resource_Timing_API) The article I came across is titled (and found at):

[Assessing Loading Performance in Real Life with Navigation and Resource Timing](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/navigation-and-resource-timing)

The two prebuilt solutions provided by that article take completely different approaches to visualizing the data you seek.

To use them without any effort, create a book mark for each of the following URLs:

- [More Detailed Analysis](http://javascript:(function()%7Bvar%20el=document.createElement(%27script%27);el.type=%27text/javascript%27;el.src=%27https://micmro.github.io/performance-bookmarklet/dist/performanceBookmarklet.min.js%27;el.onerror=function()%7Balert(%22Looks%20like%20the%20Content%20Security%20Policy%20directive%20is%20blocking%20the%20use%20of%20bookmarklets%5Cn%5CnYou%20can%20copy%20and%20paste%20the%20content%20of:%5Cn%5Cn%5C%22https://micmro.github.io/performance-bookmarklet/dist/performanceBookmarklet.min.js%5C%22%5Cn%5Cninto%20your%20console%20instead%5Cn%5Cn(link%20is%20in%20console%20already)%22);console.log(%22https://micmro.github.io/performance-bookmarklet/dist/performanceBookmarklet.min.js%22);%7D;document.getElementsByTagName(%27body%27)%5B0%5D.appendChild(el);%7D)();) <-- copy this link to your bookmarks collection
- [Performance Waterfall](http://javascript:(function()%7Bvar%20el=document.createElement(%27script%27);el.type=%27text/javascript%27;el.src=%27https://randycasburn.github.io/waterfall/waterfall.js%27;document.getElementsByTagName(%27body%27)%5B0%5D.appendChild(el);%7D)();) <-- copy this link to your bookmarks collection

As mentioned, these are *bookmarklets*. They contain JavaScript code that can be executed directly on the page you have loaded. To use them,

1. Load the page in Chrome that you want performance data
2. Open you bookmarks and click on one of the two bookmarklets provided here

The result will be the waterfall or other detailed data you are seeking.

> Note: The script can be blocked by content-security-policy and may not
> work on all sites.

#### Source Code

The waterfall chart like you originally asked about can be found at the following link. Note I am hosting this file for your answer. I can't guarantee it will be available forever. Please download and host the file. (Open License)

[Waterfall](https://github.com/andydavies/waterfall) by [Andy Davies](https://twitter.com/AndyDavies)

The more detailed version is found here: (MIT License)

[Performance-Bookmarklet](https://github.com/micmro/performance-bookmarklet) by [Michael Mrowetz](https://twitter.com/micmro).

### File Upload

You'll see the Resource Timing API provides this data. If you prefer to use the XHR API the a simple way to measure file upload time is by using `xhr.upload` object which takes an event listener for progress. As pointed out, this isn't necessary given the previous tools.

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      // Initialize and finalize a timer here
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        console.log(evt.loaded + "/" + evt.total);
      }
    }, false);
```

### Server Processing Time

In order to achieve the goal of measuring performance of the server and reporting it back to the client, the server must be involved in order to share its internal processing timing that you seek in your question. There is no way to determine that from the browser alone.

I recommend the use of the [Server-Timing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Server-Timing) feature with details about its use in the [PerformanceServerTiming API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceServerTiming)

It is fairly simple to use this API. As the example shows (using a NodeJS server), all your server has to do is respond with a specific HTTP header that contains the performance data you would like to display in the browser:

```
const headers = {
    'Server-Timing': `
      cache;desc="Cache Read";dur=23.2,
      db;dur=53,
      app;dur=47.2
    `.replace(/\n/g, '')
  };
```

Using the information on the client is as simple as this (from the MDN link page):

```
let entries = performance.getEntriesByType('resource');
console.log(entries[0].serverTiming);
// 0: PerformanceServerTiming {name: "cache", duration: 23.2, description: "Cache Read"}
// 1: PerformanceServerTiming {name: "db", duration: 53, description: ""}
// 2: PerformanceServerTiming {name: "app", duration: 47.2, description: ""}
```

Comment: Hi Randy. I didn't use your full answer, but awarded you the points for the amazing help and effort. However, part of the solution was found something you alluded to with `xhr.upload.addEventListener`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

1. For monitoring the upload state, I think you need `XMLHttpRequestUpload`  and `request.upload.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress) or request.onprogress`  and `onloadend` to check the `loadend` event. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/upload.
2. I don't see there is a partucular HTTP state to determine the start of a response from a server. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status. So from the HTTP API level (`XMLHttpRequest`) I dont think you can find a clue of that. But the browser should be able to know from TCP level. If checking devtools is not your preference, you may need to specify the timestamp in the response. Once the client gets the response, the client knows the start time of the response.
3. The client can easily get the time that it receives the response from the server.

So

`Dur_uploading = Time_loadend - Time_requeststarts`

`Dur_serverprocessing = Time_responsespecified - Time_loadend`

`Dur_download = Time_responsereceived - Time_resonsespecified`